# How to set the indentation of BibTeX in JabRef?

Tags: jabref

Anyone knows how to set the indentation of BibTeX in JabRef? I want it to look like this:[image: So here the = signs are aligned]

So here the = signs are aligned

How can I do that in JabRef. I've been playing with the options in JabRef for hours and still have no clue..

===added 21 Feb===

what I mean is mine looks like this:

[image: my Jabref]

Comment: What do you mean ? JabRef always left  the equal sings aligned, just go to another reference and return, et voilá, the signs are now aligned.

Comment: My suggestion would be to [submit a feature request](https://github.com/JabRef/jabref/issues)...

Comment: They've recently changed the approach to formatting 'raw' entries: this is 'by design' and I'm not sure what if anything is exposed to users. In any case, this looks to me like a feature request (and thus off-topic).

Comment: If submitting a feature request, please state why you want to have the equal signs globally starting at the same column. The reasoning for starting the `{` at most far right column at *each* entry was that *each entry* looks nice locally and you can do easily copy and pasting end emailing without letting other users think "WTF, what a waste of space". - The [current development strategy](https://github.com/JabRef/jabref/wiki/Development-Strategy) states that configuration settings are to be removed to improve the overall quality and stability of JabRef.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. It makes sense to keep the format a bit tighter, but it'd be nice if there is an option for the users. But I'm ok with both so no need for a feature request.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `JabRef-2.10` go into `Options->Preferences->File->Field Saving options` It is in the lower right. Then enable button "Start field contents in same column":

[image]

Then you'll get this view and also in the saved bib file:

[image]

Comment: Which JabRef release do you have? I don't see this in v3.2

Comment: I have the Ubuntu version 2.10 and I see it is gone in 3.2

Comment: OK, so that matches up with what I thought: this is deliberate

Comment: I'm also using 3.2 in Window and I can't see these options. Why would they remove this...

Comment: A discussion can be read at https://github.com/JabRef/jabref/issues/116. Please show up at the [users mailinglist](https://sourceforge.net/p/jabref/mailman/jabref-users/) or comment on the issue.